# Call jsp page from autocompete function in liferay

Tags: java, jquery, liferay

```jquery
$(function() {
    $("#ac1").autocomplete('getdata.jsp');
}
```

I'm calling that page in liferay6..
so, What sort of changes I will have to make in `portlet.xml` and another file ..
I'm getting this error....

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/getdata.jsp?q=abc 404 Not Found
```

(This error is coming in Firebug not in UI)

Thanks in Advance,
Mayur Patel

Comment: The error link you provided lives on your local machine and is thus rather invisible to anyone who doesn't have access to you machine. Could please post the details of the error, or provide a link that people we access.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using a portlet specific resource as the data, you should probably be using [portlet:resourceURL](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/sdk_portletcontaineru5/#Resource_Serving) or liferay-portlet:resourceURL instead of a static address to the file getdata.jsp. ResourceURLs create fully qualified URLs that target your own portlet. The resource served are supposed to be content fragments instead of full blown pages. That way they are especially suitable for AJAX-calls.

Where is the getdata.jsp file located? You could define the full path to the file i.e. /my-service/getdata.jsp instead of relying on the relative address that points to the /web/guest url-mapping. That way you can be sure that the file is found provided that you are not going to share the portlet with others that might not install the portlet the same way as you have done.